# Is there a way to select a group and copy in Kicad Schematic Editor?

Tags: kicad

I know we can do that in Eagle by selecting a block and copying them. Has Ki cad Implemented such feature? It documentation says I need to hold "SHIFT" Key and select to copy. Doesn't Work!!

`Application: kicad
Version: 4.0.7 release build
wxWidgets: Version 3.0.3 (debug,wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1011,GCC 7.1.0,wx containers,compatible with 2.8)
Platform: Windows 8 (build 9200), 64-bit edition, 64 bit, Little endian, wxMSW
Boost version: 1.60.0
Curl version: libcurl/7.54.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.23.1 librtmp/2.3
         USE_WX_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT=OFF
         USE_WX_OVERLAY=OFF
         KICAD_SCRIPTING=ON
         KICAD_SCRIPTING_MODULES=ON
         KICAD_SCRIPTING_WXPYTHON=ON
         USE_FP_LIB_TABLE=HARD_CODED_ON
         BUILD_GITHUB_PLUGIN=ON`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should.  If it doesn't, that's definitely a bug.

As an alternative, select with your mouse, right-click and go to "Save", which is KiCad 4's way of saying "Copy".  Then use the paste icon to insert a copy of the block you selected.

-- Addendum --

It occurs to me that you might be holding SHIFT and clicking to copy an item.  KiCad only supports the idea of copying a block of items.  You would need to hold SHIFT and then click+drag to select and copy the items.  To duplicate a single item, you need to use the SHIFT and click+drag action but only allow the selection box to cover a single item.

Comment: Reboot solved the issue! I don't know how. #Windows lol

Comment: this is not working in kiCad 5.1.10

Answer (score 1):

First: make a block by driving the mouse about the area to copy. Press the left mouse key and mark the area.
Second: press Ctrl + c to copy this area
Third: press Ctrl + v to insert the marked area and place the copy.

Comment: this only works inside the same PCB layout , and not between 2 different PCB layouts

Answer (score -1):

Press and hold "G" key (in KiCad it performs Grab/Move) while left click and hold mouse button to draw a selection rectangle around items. Pheww it was hard to write/describe wasn't it?